# Working with accounts and user generated data in Django

Tags: django, web-applications

I haven't found any documentation or tutorials on this topic, haven't received any answers on the IRC channel either so it makes me think I'm looking for the wrong thing. Anyway, resorting to SO after several hours of searching. I'll try to describe what I'm after by example:

1. I want to create a web application where user could create an account (this part is rather clear
2. After logging in, user would be able to store his favorite meals
3. When a user is logged in, he would see a list of his favorite meals and he could edit them

I understand how user can create account and log in. But everything after that is kind of blurry.

After user logs in, let's say he would be presented with a form he could fill in and save. How should the database (models) be designed to handle this? Would each user get his own table? How to retrieve the user stored data (i.e. favorite foods) from the database?

These are the things I'm trying to figure out while learning django/programming in general. As I said I haven't found it described in any books, docs or tutorials I went through.

I would appreciate if you could point me to the right direction. I feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic stuff:

1. make a foreign key for the user in your model
2. suppress the user field from the form
3. save the form with commit=False, set the user to the authenticated user and save the model.

The rest you can get pretty straight forward from the tutorial.

For example:

```
# At models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class FavoriteMeal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # other fields...

# At forms.py
class FavoriteMealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FavoriteMeal
        exclude = ('user', )

# At views.py
@login_required
def favorite_meals_view(request):
    favorite_meals = FavoriteMeal.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FavoriteMealForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            favorite_meal = form.save(commit=False)
            favorite_meal.user = request.user
            favorite_meal.save()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is for is really very basic part of django. I would suggest you to go through tutorial. This would give you a fair amount of idea of how the model relationship could be used to store the data.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I went through this tutorial but it doesn't deal with user accounts.